# Installing a 50 Amp breaker for 220 circuit, using a direct burial cable for 100' for use of electric 220 welder

Tags: wiring

What size or guage electrical cable do I need if I am installing a 50Amp Breaker in panel and going 100' to run a 220 volt welder?

Comment: I gather that the welder is not outdoors... will there be any other electrical loads in the building the welder is at?   Is it a 120/240V welder or 240V-only (no neutral)? Short answer: UF 6/3 but it may be more complicated than that, or possibly more simple.

Comment: Can you give us the actual I1eff (or nameplate primary current + max duty cycle) for your welder?  Welders are weird...

Answer (score 1):

A welder is defined as a non continuous load so the wire can be sized at 100% of the listed nameplate  per table 630.11.A. But a 50 amp breaker you would need at least #6 copper. I would upsize a bit and put a sub panel in so more could be done than the welder only.